# What does the lack of singular points of non liniar system mean in phase portraits?

Tags: nonlinear-system

I'm going to plot the phase portrait of this system:

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-x^2 + 4 y^2$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-8 - 4 y + 2 x y$

The singular point $(x,y)$ can be found from the system:

$-x^2 + 4 y^2=0$

$-8 - 4 y + 2 x y=0$

Seems this system doesn't have roots [wolframalfa](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=system%20of%20equations&assumption=%22FSelect%22%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%7D,%20%22dflt%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22,%20%22equation1%22%7D%20-%3E%224y%5E2-x%5E2%3D0%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22,%20%22equation2%22%7D%20-%3E%222xy-4y-8%3D0%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22,%20%22system%20of%20equations%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22,%20%22dflt%22%7D). What does it mean? I have integral curves(phase trajectories) that do not intersect? If yes, hence, obviously I can't determine type of the singular point ?

By the way, I heard from my lector, that it can be drawn in Wolframalfa. Can you provide an example respectively to my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system that you have given has indeed two singular points:
$$x_1 = -2,\qquad y_1 = -1,$$
and
$$X_2 = 4, \qquad y_2 = 2;$$
You can verify this by checking that $dx/dt$ and $dy/dt$ are both zero.

To check what type of singular points these are, we can study the system linearized around a stable point:
$$ \dot x \approx A x $$
where $A = \nabla f (\bar x)$. In this case, we get that
$$
A(x,f) = \nabla f(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} -2x & 8y \\ 2y & -4+2x \end{bmatrix}.$$

This matrix has two eigenvalues,
$$ \lambda_{1,2}(x,y) = -2 \pm \sqrt{4-8x + 4x^2 + 16x^2},$$
of which, in the case of the two given stable points, one is positive:
$$ \lambda_1(x_1,y_1) \approx 5.21$$
$$ \lambda_1(x_2,y_2) = 8 $$
Because the linearized system has positive eigenvalues, the singular points are unstable.

To draw the phase portrait you can use a
[vector field plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=vector%20field%20plot%20(-x%5E2%20%2B2%20y%5E2,%202xy%20-%208%20%2B4y)).

Comment: Thank You very much. I understood stuff around linear systems, but didn't understand how to get lambda from nonlinear. In addition I want to ask You about two more things. At first, I found two equations for lambda, it is $\lambda=\dfrac{a+d}{2}+-\sqrt{\dfrac{(a+d)^2-4(ad-bc)}{4}}$,    and the second was the same but with $4detA$ under the root. Which is true?

Comment: And the second one is how to linearize the system to get a,b,c,d?  It was the step, where I stuck.

Comment: You linearize the nonlinear system by taking the first approximation in the taylor expansion. The entry $i,j$ of the matrix $A$ is the partial derivative of the $i$th equation with respect to the $j$th variable.
As for the eigenvalues, the formulas you show are the same, as $detA = ad-bc$ :)

Comment: Understood yet, thank You